# Creating javascript objects out of list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I'm having a small issue creating objects out of list items in an unordered list. I'm creating a gallery and I need for each gallery thumbnail to be it's own object, so I'm iterating through each list item using jQuery's $.each()

The problem is I don't know how to give each object/li it's own instance name.

Here's the code:

```
    function galleryButton(){
        this.link
        this.name
        this.image
        this.identifier,
        this.goPage = function(){
        $('.container').animate({opacity : '0'}, 500).load(this.link + ' .galContainer', function(){$('.container').animate({opacity : '1'})});
        return false;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache:false
        });

        $('.gallery li a').each(function(node, value){
            this = new galleryButton();
            this.link = $(this).attr('href');
            this.name = $(this).attr('name');
            this.image = $(this + " img").attr('src');
            this.identifier = $(this).attr('data-pic-id');

            $(this).click(this.goPage);
        })

        $('.goback').click(function(){

            var back = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.container').animate({opacity : '0'}, 500).load(back + ' .gallery', function(){$('.container').animate({opacity : '1'})});
                return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: You cannot assign to the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesnt make any sense:

```
   $('.gallery li a').each(function(node, value){
        this = new galleryButton();
        this.link = $(this).attr('href');
        this.name = $(this).attr('name');
        this.image = $(this + " img").attr('src');
        this.identifier = $(this).attr('data-pic-id');

        $(this).click(this.goPage);
    });
```

You dont want to override `this`, you want to create a new object like:

```
        var slide = new galleryButton();
        slide.link = $(this).attr('href');
        slide.name = $(this).attr('name');
        slide.image = $(this + " img").attr('src');
        slide.identifier = $(this).attr('data-pic-id');
```

So in this case `slide` is the instance name, but it is only going to exist within the scope of that function each callback function.

Now if you need to able to access these objects then you either need to create the variables outside the function or put them somewhere else accessible. Were it me i would store them in the `data` for the `li` like:

```
        var slide = new galleryButton();
        slide.link = $(this).attr('href');
        slide.name = $(this).attr('name');
        slide.image = $(this + " img").attr('src');
        slide.identifier = $(this).attr('data-pic-id');
        $(this).closest('li).data('slide', slide);
```

Then you can access them like `$(someSelectorToGetTheLI).data('slide')`.

Comment: How do I access the properties of the objects with $(someSelectToGetLI).data('slide)? Would I go $(thing).data('slide).link?

Comment: Yes, but you should always make sure you actually have the object - if you havent set it with `.data` yet then `.data` will return `undefined` so using `.link` directly would throw an error. So something like: `sliceObj = $(someSelectToGetLI).data('slide'); if(slide) {  // do stuff like slide.link }`

Answer (score 1):

Don't store your galleryButton into the "this" variable. Make a new var,

```
var myGalleryButton = new galleryButton();
```

And update your assignments:

```
myGalleryButton.link = $(this).attr('href');
/// etc
```

And then at the end of the .each() function, push myGalleryButton to an array/object for later access.